# Zingchart plotting X-axis with Times, not Dates

Tags: javascript, datetime, plot, transform, zingchart

I want to plot data with my X-axis representing Timespans (elapsed times), not actual dates.

I have a series with the following (string) values:

times: "00:00:00", "00:01:00", "00:10:00", "00:11:00"

I parse these values into (int)

times: 0, 6000, 60000, 66000

But when I draw the graph, the hour field is wrong. It shows "2" instead of "0" or "00". Minutes and seconds seem fine:
[image]

Here is my json code. I played with the Hours field, with no success:

```
// Description of the graph to be displayed
vm.chartJson = {
   type: 'line',
   scaleX: {
      transform: {  
         type: 'date',  
         all: '%H:%h:%G:%g:%i:%s'  
      }
   },
   series: [{ values: data }]
};
```

How can I display the Hours field, while still manipulating TIMES and not Datetimes? How would that go if the total number of hours goes above 24? I would be okay with either displaying the total number of hours, or adding a day field. Example:
"124:22:01" or
"5:4:22:01"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the issue:

```
// Determine the format of x-axis
var format = '%i:%s';
if (data[data.length - 1][0] >= 3600000) format = '%G:%i:%s';

// Description of the graph to be displayed
vm.chartJson = {
  type: 'line',
     scaleX: {
     transform: {  
        type: 'date',  
        all: format
     }
  },
  series: [{ values: data }],
  "utc": true,
  "timezone": 0
};
```

I can't display Hours more than 24, so I could display days if needed.

Answer (score 2):

One issue I can note is we take time in milliseconds. So one minute = 60000 milliseconds. This could be the first thing off. Tack on a zero to the end of all your values.

The second issue, I cannot duplicate your times exactly because your local machine timezone is being used and I think mine is different. We have attributes that account for this, but it may not be necessary. Read further.

You cannot display 124 hours natively in the library. Depending on your input data you can just format and plot your own values with a custom x-axis label and tokens. Since you seem to already have the string format you want, why not just continue to use that?

```js
var customLabels = ['00:00:00', '00:01:00', '00:10:00','00:11:00'];
var myConfig = {
  type: 'line',
  scaleX: {
    labels: customLabels
  },
  tooltip: {
    textAlign: 'left',
    text: '%kl<br>OR<br>%data-dates: %v'
  },
 series: [
  {
   values: [475, 420, 400, 500],
   dataDates: customLabels, // one for each point in values array
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Relative Documentation:

[demo link](https://demos.zingchart.com/view/COPVTKWF)

[tokens](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/zingchart-tokens/). Third one down in the grid is custom tokens starting with `data-`.

[tooltips](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/tooltips/)

[scales](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/configure-chart-scales/)

Comment: Hu Nardecky. Thanks for the reply. It was indeed a problem with my local time. On January 1st, 1970, my machine's time was already 2 AM. Hence the 2. You solution won't fit because I lose the scale on the x-axis. It's as if the time between 0 et 1min was as long as 1min and 10min.